# Cosmos DB query element count

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I would like to find find how many times an element occurs.From the sample I want to get the element count. If we see the data. Elements appear twice also the inner element like Name appears twice. Like that I want to find the count of element occurrence.

I tried seeing some group by clause and could not find any group by option in CosmosDB.

{ "data": [ [ { "Elements": [ { "Name": "Ma", "Gender": "Male", "City": "Newyork", "State": "Newyork" }, { "Gender": "Female", "City": "Los Angeles", "State": "California" }, { "Name": "Bruce", "Gender": "Male", "City": "Chicago" } ], "Subdivided": [ { "Low": "20", "Block": "227", "Subcode": "MIRROR", "Legal_Desc_Map_Plat_Type_Indicator": "PLA" } ], "Elements": [ { "Name": "Ma", "Gender": "Male", "City": "Newyork" }, { "Gender": "Female", "City": "Los Angeles", "State": "California" }, { "Name": "Bruce", "Gender": "Male", "State": "Illinois" } ] } ] ], "_ts": 1559463991 }

Result something like.
Element = 2, Element.Name = 2 etc like that.

[image: See screen for some info]

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Jay, Is it possible to query without data[0]?

Comment: not sure what's your meaning. data[0] is based on your data format,if you remove the Outermost layer `[]`, you don't need `data[0]`.

Comment: So,any further explanations?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,your screenshot is impossible.`Elements` key can't duplicate in single object.

Your requirement could be implemented by the `COUNT` aggregate function.

For Elements:

```
SELECT value(count(data.Elements))
FROM c
join data in c.data
```

Result:

[image]

For Name:

```
SELECT value(count(elem.Name))
FROM c
join data in c.data
join elem in data.Elements
```

Result:

[image]

---

For your further need:

Since Aggregates are not allowed in the WHERE clause,

[image]

maybe you need to process the results by yourself. `Group By` is not supported naturally([feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18561901-add-group-by-support-for-aggregate-functions)),however you could get know about a great package [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) based on DocumentDb stored procedure. You could count the `elements` and group by some other columns,like `id`.

Comment: Hi Jay, I will try to better with my screen shots. You query is almost there but need little more help. If you see "Elements" are in multiple array so the data did not return value as you stated but if I changes to this it worked (like data[0].Elements). Is it possible to help with placing in Where clause to pick with the count is more than 1.                                     SELECT value(count(elem.Name))
FROM c
join data in c.data
join elem in data[0].Elements.

Comment: @RSimple Oh,because i removed one nested `[]`,so i don't need to use data[0]. Forget it!